Hidden sidebar feature on desktop Saas apps
I am currently designing a B2B Saas application for a startup, and I am having confusion while deciding the collapsable states of the sidebar - either collapsed with icons or completely hidden with just a menu icon left on screen. What are your thoughts on having the sidebar completely disappear?

In my view, that depends on the rest of the design (can you post a scribble of the two states)?

If the collapsed state of the sidebar shows an empty strip down the left side of the window, I would add the (interactive) icons to it, so that there's some value in the space used.

If, on the other hand, the remaining menu icon which is left on the screen can be integrated into the rest of the layout, without an empty strip of whitespace on the left side of the screen, the sidebar may disappear completely.


If going for the second option, be sure that the navigation really is needed rarely, because it needs two clicks (open sidebar, click icon). If users need the navigation often (i.e., not only the typical Settings, Help, About entries, but real business functions), then I would go for the first option.

By the way, Welcome to the site! I realized you're a first time contributor only after posting the answer...
